# Exception Error not printing

Tags: python, list

Hi, I wrote a thesaurus function and i am trying to get it to raise an exception, this is a extract as an example where i would like it to raise an exception.

```
     #Extract from thesaurus function
     if words.count(value) > 1:
            raise Exception("Word appears twice")
```

This is the last line of the function for now and i follow this up with a try statement to open the file containing the words.

```
    try:
        file = open("thesaurus.txt", "r")
        words = file.readlines()
        Thesaurus(words)
        print("Successful")
    except LookupError as exceptObj:
            print("Error:", str(exceptObj))
```

All the statements that should throw an exception(i tested the code outside the function as a standalone code and it worked) but as a function, the exception does it raise plus it prints successful when it should not, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The exception thrown by the `Thesaurus` method (`Exception`) is more general than the one that you are catching in the `except` block (`LookupError`). So it will not be handled.

Change

```
raise Exception("Word appears twice")
```

to

```
raise LookupError("Word appears twice")
```

Comment: Could you shed some more light on the issue by posting more (relevant) code, so that your situation could be reproduced exactly as it is ?

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing some type of exception and catching another type. You need to throw and catch the same type.

Either you change the line

```
raise Exception("Word appears twice")
```

to

```
raise LookupError("Word appears twice")
```

Or change the line

```
except LookupError as exceptObj
```

to

```
except Exception as exceptObj
```